# Firefox selecting .mp4 video instead of .ogv

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, video

So I have this peculiar problem with HTML5 , whenever I try to play my video on my website with Firefox it plays the .mp4 video instead of the .ogv

Code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <video id="player" width="100%" height="auto" title="" controls runat="server" onclick="this.play();">
        <source runat="server" id="ffVideo" type="video/ogv" onclick="this.play();" />
        <source runat="server" id="mp4Video" type="video/mp4" onclick="this.play();" />
      </video>
      <embed id="playerOld" width="680px" autostart="false" allowfullscreen="true" height="383px"
        title="" style="display: none" type="application/mp4" runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

The src gets filled dynamically from the code behind.

Code behind:

```
Public Property vidSrc As String
    Get
      Return player.Attributes("src")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
      mp4Video.Attributes("src") = Value + ".mp4"
      ffVideo.Attributes("src") = Value + ".ogv"
      playerOld.Attributes("src") = Value + ".mp4"
    End Set
  End Property
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gecko recognizes the following MIME types as Ogg files:

- audio/ogg
  An Ogg file containing only audio.
- video/ogg
  An ogg file containing video (and possibly also audio).
- application/ogg
  An Ogg file with unspecified content. Using one of the other two MIME types is preferred, but you can use this if you don't know what the contents of the file are.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

no video/ogv in the list which is why it uses the one format it does support

Comment: Thank you! It now selects the proper video, now I only have a problem with the controls which aren't working properly in FF

Comment: Nevermind, that was due to the onClick event on the source which FF automatically implements, thanks!